# CCAVENUE Payment Gateway integration with Android app

Tags: android, ccavenue

We are developing a product which collects dues/rents from apartment occupants. We use CCavenue and PayPal payment gateway in web application to do this functionality. We are developing Android app for the same application.

I don't have any idea how to integrate Android with CCavenue.

Comment: Me also looking for the answer, if you implemented successfully then share the answer.

Comment: anyone of you got through ??

Comment: Are you using PHP or ASP for submission??

Comment: @William  I have CCavenue loginid password but there is no any api given, so just want an idea from where we start the integration. There is integration method also but dont know how to use.

Comment: here is the things i found in CCAvenue is there anyone who used this way for payment

http://i.stack.imgur.com/rTRhT.png

Comment: hii am also plan to integrate can any one found the solution let me know plse

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We are using CCAvenue w/an app in android. You need to request for the Android Integration Kit in addition to your test account credentials such as: MerchanId, Access Code, Encryption Key, from CCAvenue then you can do a "Seamless" integration with your Android App. Next, you will need to follow this data flow:

1. Request for payment options from Mobile App to CCAvenue
2. JSON data with payment options returned
3. Request for encryption key from Mobile App to Merchant server
4. Request for encryption key from Merchant server to CCAvenue
5. Dynamic encryption key returned
6. Encryption key sent from Merchant server to Mobile App
7. Transaction with encrypted data sent from Mobile App to CCavenue
8. Processed transaction status returned to Merchant server
9. Transaction status pulled by Mobile App

Hope this helps!

Comment: You need to register for their service. after validation of required documents they provide you the android integration api and guide to set up payment gateway.

Comment: which encryption you are using to send data into server

Comment: at what point do you store data in your database (assuming for it to be on your  web server)

Comment: Thanks for the info, do we need to go for PCI compliance in this approach?

Comment: I have looked at there encryption technique. It is not up to date as market. I think ccavenue is afraid of exposing more on coding side. All codes in the documentation are in bits and pieces.