# How to Integrate CCAvenue gateway in Android App can anyone explain in detailed i want to use Non-Seamless way

Tags: android, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I want to integrate CCAvenue payment gateway in my app, But I didn't find any help. Please help me.

Comment: Try on _Google_ at least once

Comment: I google it, but I didn't find any steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CCAVENUE Payment Gateway integration with android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737691/ccavenue-payment-gateway-integration-with-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

From your question first you have to find your merchant type and after that you have to follow the steps provided in documentation of ccavenue sdk sample 
here you can contact the ccavenue guys for your sdk sample or any other query http://www.ccavenue.com/inapp_payments.jsp

Steps:

1. Request for payment options is sent from Mobile App to CCAvenue
2. On receiving the request for payment options, JSON data with payment options is returned by CCAvenue.
3. Request for encryption key from Mobile App is submitted to the Merchant server.
4. Request for encryption key from Merchant server is submitted to CCAvenue.
5. On receiving the request from Merchant server, Dynamic encryption key is returned by CCAvenue.
6. Encryption key is sent from Merchant server to Mobile App.
7. On submission of encryption key to the application, transaction with encrypted data is sent from Mobile App to CCAvenue.
8. Processed transaction status returned by CCAvenue to Merchant server.
9. Transaction status pulled by Mobile App.