# integrate ccavenue payment gateway in android

Tags: android, payment-gateway, ccavenue

i am developing android app. now i want to add CCavenue gateway for the payment. i have googled it but cant find best solution. i am new user for payment gateway. i don't have much knowledge about payment gateway.
i found some **Seamless**  and **Non Seamless** method to use this gateway. and one other solution i found is using **webview**. i have refer this que : [CCAVENUE Payment Gateway integration with Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737691/ccavenue-payment-gateway-integration-with-android-app) .
so can any have idea about CCavenue payment gateway then please share with me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From your question first you have to find your merchant type and after that you have to follow the steps provided in documentation of ccavenue sdk sample 
[here](http://www.ccavenue.com/inapp_payments.jsp) you can contact the ccavenue guys for your sdk sample or any other query

Steps:

1. Request for payment options is sent from Mobile App to CCAvenue
2. On receiving the request for payment options, JSON data with payment options is returned by CCAvenue.
3. Request for encryption key from Mobile App is submitted to the Merchant server.
4. Request for encryption key from Merchant server is submitted to CCAvenue.
5. On receiving the request from Merchant server, Dynamic encryption key is returned by CCAvenue.
6. Encryption key is sent from Merchant server to Mobile App.
7. On submission of encryption key to the application, transaction with encrypted data is sent from Mobile App to CCAvenue.
8. Processed transaction status returned by CCAvenue to Merchant server.
9. Transaction status pulled by Mobile App.

Comment: i have checked it out. but i want simple sample code.

Comment: contact ccavenue guys have you check link which i have provide for the contact the team? you can find contactus number and mail they will provide you the sample code in eclipse and studio whatever you want

Comment: i have show this post and steps in stack overflow before you gave me ans.

Comment: i have down Cc avenue integration  with my own code. but i want some reliable code.

Comment: i have show this post before you gave me ans : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737691/ccavenue-payment-gateway-integration-with-android-app?rq=1

Comment: not exactly but also not  yet successfully integrate. code in progress may be after some time i will integrate.