# How to integrate CCAvenue to Ionic app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I want to integrate ccavenue to my hybrid app that I am building on Ionic but I am unable to find any example or code or any other thing which can be helpful in this. Plz let me know if you have any information regarding this.

**Update**:
Ccavenue didn't work for me even with the iframe because iframe can only work on the registered domain (ie. www.example.com) and not any other place so I left it and choose the [Razorpay Payment gateway](https://razorpay.com/) because it provides official support for Ionic/Cordova.

Here is the sample app.
https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova-sample-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737691/ccavenue-payment-gateway-integration-with-android-app Follow this steps and contact ccavenue team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to integrate CCavenue on my Ionic app. You have to do the following

- By default ccavenue blocks all ip addresses from showing payment page
  except the url by which user has registered.
- First check what ip address is being used by the app while run through `ionic serve` , ask the ccavenue support to whitelist that ip and also port `8100` or whatever your app is using.
- Once you've whitelisted the ip now you have to make sure that [`inappbrowser plugin`](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/) is installed in the `ionic` now you have to submit the payment form to another window by using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34357114/6613333)

I hope it will help many.

Comment: @RaviMehta try this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342172/post-a-form-in-a-new-window-inappbrowser-in-ionic-cordova/34357114#34357114

Comment: @SuhailAKhtar : Can I use the same for IONIC 2?

Answer (score 1):

**iFrame Integration**

https://www.ccavenue.com/ccavenue_index.jsp#feature-block12

Hope this helps you

Comment: Hi John, I am trying to get it work but it is not working showing error 10002. My backend is on php. can u plz walk me through.

Comment: its my due to incorrect merchant ID, incorrect Access code and unregistered URL. You should use your registered URL.

Comment: You can also check the razorpay. They provided cordova plugin and .js integration for web devolepment. Go through this link https://razorpay.com/

Answer (score 1):

Suhail,

You may not be able to get it done through iFrames as rightly said by some of the members here.

So you can get around it by having a return url on the server and storing the success/failure message along with other details in temp DB on server, check it from the mobile application from an API and decide whether the payment is done or not.

We have done same with snovel.in application and it works perfectly fine with PayUMoney. Only thing you have to remember is checking constantly from mobile application about success or failure of the payment becomes critical.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @aditya for your answer. Actually I was not able to go to the payement page of ccavenue on a hybrid app so now I am using razorpay and it supports hybrid apps as well

Comment: I am going to implement this in few days of time, may be once I am done will let you know how got it implemented. Might not be useful for you but might be useful for someone else.

Comment: That would be helpful for others but now I have moved to razorpay

Comment: Hi Aditya, Have u completed ur integration.

Comment: @SuhailAKhtar : Yes I did complete the integration, and you have rightly said the steps in below answer. I hope you have resolved the integration and if not do let me know I can share the code with you.

Comment: I am glad that it worked. I have already implemented it. My request to you is to create a sample app and share the link of github here so that others can get the help as well.