# How can i add CCavenue in progressive web app , i am using ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, ccavenue

Can anybody help me with the ccavenue integration in the ionic app? I am not able to open the ccavenue in iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this post: [cordova - How to integrate CCAvenue to Ionic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254907/cordova-how-to-integrate-ccavenue-to-ionic2). As per thread,

> You need to set up a CCAvenue account. Go to the Sign Up page, choose the Startup Pro plan and fill out your details. On creating your account, you will recieve an e-mail on your entered e-mail address to verify your e-mail. Once you verify your e-mail, you will recieve an activation e-mail which will give you your CCAvenue Account Login ID and you will be required to set your password. Set your account password amd make sure you read the e-mails that you receive thoroughly. Login to CCAvenue M.A.R.S Panel (Dashboard). In the Settings > API keys tab , you would get the Merchant ID , Access Code as well as the Working Key. The working key is also named as the encryption key in the dashboard provided to your from CCAvenue. Copy these keys to a safe place for later use. To secure the data transmitted from mobile while initiating the transaction, CCAvenue has implemented a time-based RSA key pair value which needs to be fetched uniquely for every transaction. These files should be uploaded on your web server.

Also from this link: [How to integrate CCAvenue to Ionic app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738996/how-to-integrate-ccavenue-to-ionic-app), you have to do the following:

> - By default ccavenue blocks all ip addresses from showing payment page
>     except the url by which user has registered.
> - First check what ip address is being used by the app while run through `ionic serve` , ask the ccavenue support to whitelist that ip and also port `8100` or whatever your app is using.
> - Once you've whitelisted the ip now you have to make sure that [`inappbrowser plugin`](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/) is installed in the `ionic` now you have to submit the payment form to another window by using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34357114/6613333)

Comment: Hi abielita ,thank you for you help but i am creating a PWA app. and if i use the inappbrowser plugin then i won't be able to use ionic build .